# Aus/von Unterschied

Tags: preposition

Welche Variante ist korrekt?

Max kommt aus der Schule.
Max kommt von der Schule.

Max kommt aus der Bank.
Max kommt von der Bank.

Max kommt aus der Arbeit.
Max kommt von der Arbeit.

Martina holt das Paket von der Post.
Martina holt das Paket aus der Post.

Comment: And probably more duplicates about that particular question.

Comment: You should also specify the question: Do you just want to know which version of each sentence is correct; why it is correct; or what the differences between *aus* and *von* are in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ALL versions are correct but (may) convey different meanings...

> Max kommt aus der Schule:

Two different meanings:

> Max just left the school building. You can see him coming out. 
>   Max comes (home) from school.

Max kommt von der Schule:

Is more a direction: he comes from the direction where the school is. 
So can mean the same as the first one:

> Max comes (home) from school

BUT: Can also mean: He works for school. 
Would be in a sentence like:

> Max wants to see how our son is. He comes from his school.

In general:

AUS is usually associated with a building that you leave. 
VON means the general direction where you come from.

In case of POST there is another little twitch:

AUS der Post usually means: Picking it out from between the other letters (probably out of the post- box)
VON der Post in that case means: she was at the Post- Building and got her package there.

Comment: Thank you. Could "von der Schule" have two meanings? The first one being "I was in front of the school and went somewhere" so I came from a place nearby the school and the second one emphasizing that I came from a place where I did the action of learning, not that I came just from the building of school?

Comment: yes, these are also possible meanings